Как игнорировать сообщения от пользователя? (telebot)
markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Я не робот ☑️', callback_data='not_robot')
markup1.add(button1)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['buttons'])
def captcha(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Подтвердите, что вы не робот ', reply_markup=markup1)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def accept(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'not_robot':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Подтверждено')
            

@bot.message_handler()
def error(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нежелательная строка')

Бот отправляет сообщение с кнопкой. Если пользователь на неё нажмёт, всё сработает корректно. Однако, если пользователь решит отправить боту какое-нибудь сообщение перед тем, как нажать на кнопку, то выведется "Нежелательная строка". Нужно сделать так, чтобы бот игнорировал любые сообщения от пользователя до тех пор, пока не будет нажата кнопка. Как это можно сделать?

Ну заведите глобальную переменную что-то типа confirmation_in_progress = True перед отправкой кнопки. Ну и проверяйте в реакции на сообщения, что если эта переменная True, то ничего не писать пользователю. А после обработки подтверждения сбросьте эту переменную.

@CrazyElf Спасибо!
